# How does Smart-contract's storage works?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, storage

I keep hearing that for each contract there is a storage as contiguous array (to have constant O(1) lookup) with 2^256 slots, 32 byte each, available. But it cannot physically be true. How is it really implemented in practice? Thanks.

Comment: from where did you hear/read it? because i have never heard about it.

Comment: from the article linked in the answer from Haseeb Saeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the array taken is virtual in every aspect. Just assume that array is initlized with zero's. Since Storage is very expensive we don't need any zeros in it. unless explicitly defined by the user.

> A key/value store mapping `32-byte keys` to `32-byte values` will do the
>   job nicely. An absent key is simply defined as mapping to the value
>   zero. Because zeros don’t take up any space, storage can be reclaimed by setting a value 
>   to zero. This is incentivized in smart contracts with a gas refund
>   when you change a value to zero.

**Fixed-Sized Values**

> For known variables with fixed sizes, it makes sense to just give them
>   reserved locations in storage

```
contract StorageTest {
    uint256 a;
    uint256[2] b;

    struct Entry {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 value;
    }
    Entry c;
}
```

These slots are determined at compile time, strictly based on the order in which the variables appear in the contract code.

**Locating Dynamically-Sized Values**
For dynamic sized values like mapping Solidity uses a hash function to uniformly and repeatably compute locations for dynamically-sized values.

```
contract StorageTest {
    uint256 a;     // slot 0
    uint256[2] b;  // slots 1-2

    struct Entry {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 value;
    }
    Entry c;       // slots 3-4
    Entry[] d;
}
```

In the above code, the dynamically-sized array d is at slot 5, but the only thing that’s stored there is the size of d. The values in the array are stored consecutively starting at the hash of the slot.

**Mappings**

> A mapping requires an efficient way to find the location corresponding
>   to a given key. Hashing the key is a good start, but care must be
>   taken to make sure different mappings generate different locations.
>
> In the above code, the “location” for e is slot 6, and the location
>   for f is slot 7, but nothing is actually stored at those locations.
>   (There’s no length to be stored, and individual values need to be
>   located elsewhere.)
>
> To find the location of a specific value within a mapping, the key and
>   the mapping’s slot are hashed together.

**Combinations of Complex Types**

Dynamically-sized arrays and mappings can be nested within each other recursively. When that happens, the location of a value is found by recursively applying the calculations defined above. This sounds more complex than it is.

e.g: `g[123][0]`

Text is summary of this [article](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/).

Comment: I have read the whole article and the question actually arose from that. I understand the indexing "virtually" but how is it done in real life, because we don't have 2^256 slots.

Comment: @AnhDũngLê actually those slots never existed these are just the numbers to avoid the collision. If the system have just 100 gb than the array can only contain the data of 100gb no more.